# Java script, модальное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css

Дополнение к прошлому вопросу, который некорректно был задан.
Не могу добиться того чтобы stickybar открывался всегда до тех пор пока его не закроют, то есть и при переходе на другую страницу чтоб всегда был открыт stickybar. Вот собственно код stickybar'a:

```
<div class="popupstick">
    <span class="hlas">Hlasujte v anketě "Čtenáři Receptáře doporučují" <a href="http://www.ireceptar.cz/ctenari-doporucuji/">a získejte ZDARMA Edici Receptáře</a></span>
    <button class="close-stick" title="Close" onclick="(document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick')[0]).style.display='none';setCookie('hideModal', '2', 7) ;">x</button>
</div>
```

А вот javascript с рабочим cookie но только для popup'a.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                c = c.substring(1);
            }
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    {    
        var delay_popup = 1000;
        if (getCookie('hideModal')=="") {
            setTimeout("document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='block'", delay_popup);
        }
        if (getCookie('hideModal')=="") {
            setTimeout("document.getElementsByClassName('popupstick')[0].style.display='block'", delay_popup);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: а что у вас с js-кодом? почему два раза одно и то же условие, что за странный, оторванный от реальности `if` в конце? что за непонятные закрытые скобки `};`? еще интересно, где код открытия "стикибара"? код закрытия вижу, еще код открытия покажите.

Comment: сделал правку..

Comment: вопросы все те же: что за непонятный `if` в конце? Что за странная конструкция `} {` в середине? И что за закрытая скобка в конце? Разберитесь в коде, приведите синтаксис в порядок. Если вы откроете его в нормальном редакторе кода - он вам сразу подчеркнет красным ошибки.

Comment: зачем у вас два раза подряд одно и то же условие? объедините их.

Comment: и уточните, как себя ведет все это на данный момент? ошибку в консоль выплевывает? просто молча не работает? или что-то другое?

Comment: насчет последнего if согласен, это так пока думал че писать,ну Иван, тут дело в том что я пытаюсь все сам и пока хорошие познания только в css и html, javacript нешарю, и первая задача которая пришла в голову сделать модальное окно, простенькое. Как видно я его сделал оно работает и все равно как я это все написал, осталась последния задача для себя это сделать так чтоб модальное окно работало всегда до тех пор пока ненажмут на мой button, непонимаю как сделать запись в cookie.

Comment: все работает, но я немогу понять как сделать и как делаеться запись в cookie, чтоб посетитель видел стик всегда до того момента пока он его незакроет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44277/discussion-between---and-t0rick).